# How to edit timescaled values for summary task baseline budget cost programmatically

Tags: c#, ms-project, office-addins

I am trying to edit baseline budget cost values for specific resource assignment and specific date via Project Add-in in C#:

```
Project project = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;
var projectTask = project.ProjectSummaryTask;
foreach (Assignment item in projectTask.Assignments)
{
    var data = item.TimeScaleData(start, end,
                    PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledBaseline1BudgetCost,
                    PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleMonths, 1);
    foreach (TimeScaleValue dataItem in data)
    {
       dataItem.Value = 1000;
    }
}
```

It works fine, but the sum on each month did not calculated correct:
[image: project professional]

When I am trying to change timescaled data for summary task with same way as I used, I am getting COM error: Invalid argument value.

```
var data = projectTask.TimeScaleData(start, end,
            PjTaskTimescaledData.pjTaskTimescaledBaseline1BudgetCost,
            PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleMonths, 1);
foreach (TimeScaleValue dataItem in data)
{
    dataItem.Value = 1000;
}
```

Exception: Invalid Argument Value 
in Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task.TimeScaleData(Object StartDate, Object EndDate, PjTaskTimescaledData Type, PjTimescaleUnit TimeScaleUnit, Int32 Count).

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late, I know but...  When I was setting ActualWork, I had to add "h" on to the end, basically setting it as a string instead of  a decimal.  It's a little hard to read, but it looks like your attached image has a "p" after the number.  Try `dataItem.Value = "1000p";` instead.

This may be equivalent to your foreach loop, but I also found that it indexed starting at 1.  I had to use `data[ 1 ].Value = decHours.ToString() + "h";`.